# Oracle SQL Developer- How to force 00:00:00 hour when inserting a new DATE value

Tags: settings, oracle-sqldeveloper, date-format, hour

In my Oracle SQL Developer, i have a table with a column with DATE format. When i insert a new row into this table, and insert a new value in this column, it automatically suggestes me the current date with the current hour. 
*I would like that it automatically suggestes me current date, but with **00:00:00 hour** .* Is there some setting or parameter that i can set in my SQL Developer to have this result?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your DATE column is set with a DEFAULT of SYSDATE.  This means, for any INSERT operations which do not specify a value in your DATE column, the current date and time will populate for that row. However, if INSERT operations do specify a value in your DATE column, then the specified date value will supersede the DEFAULT of SYSDATE.

If an application is controlling INSERT operations on that table, then one solution is to ensure the application utilizes the TRUNC() function to obtain your desired results. For example:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_target
    (
    col_date,
    col_value
    )
VALUES
    (
    TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'DDD'),
    5000
    )
;
```

However, if there are multiple applications or interfaces where users could be inserting new rows into the table, (e.g. using Microsoft Access or users running INSERT statements via SQL Developer) and you can't force all of those interfaces to utilize the TRUNC() function on that column during insertion, then you need to look into other options.

If you can ensure via applications that INSERT operations will not actually reference the DATE, then you can simply ALTER the table so that the DATE column will have a DEFAULT of TRUNC(SYSDATE). A CHECK CONSTRAINT can be added for further integrity:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_target
     MODIFY
          (
          col_date DATE DEFAULT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'DDD') NOT NULL
          )
     ADD
          (
          CONSTRAINT tbl_target_CHK_dt CHECK(col_date = TRUNC(col_date, 'DDD'))
          )
;
```

However, if users *still* have the freedom to specify the DATE when inserting new rows, you will want to use a TRIGGER:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tbl_target_biu_row
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF col_val
     ON tbl_target
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

     :NEW.col_date := TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'DDD');

END tbl_target_biu_row
;
```

This will take of needing to manage the application code of all external INSERT operations on the table. Keep in mind, the above trigger is also modifying the DATE column if a user updates the specified value column.

Comment: should i run this query once and for all, and then it will always suggest me the 00:00:00 hour?

Answer (score 0):

We can't able to insert 00:00:00 hours ... the hour value should be between 1 to 12...

we can use below query to insert 00:00:00 hours but the value will be changed to 12:00:00

`INSERT INTO TABLE (DATE_COL) VALUES 
( TO_DATE ('11/16/2017 00:00:00 ', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS '));`